# Problem in exponential/log calculus question

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I have no idea how to approach this question, $\frac{dQ}{dt} = Q$ and $Q = e$ when $t = 0$, find $Q$ in terms of $t$. I can approach it logically, and the only way $y' = e$ when $t = 0$ is $y= e^{t+1}$, how do I solve it algebraically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $Q\gt0$
$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=Q$$
By rearranging
$$\frac{dQ}{Q}=dt$$
by Integrating both sides we get

> Note:$$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln|x|+C \text{ and } \int dx =x+C$$

$$\ln Q=t+C$$
$$\ln e=C$$
$$\implies C=1$$
By putting everything back we get

> $$\ln Q=t+1 \implies Q=e^{t+1}$$

Comment: Thanks, I got it with your hint in the beginning but why do you assume Q>0, does it change the question?

Comment: @user145591 $$\int \frac{dx}{x}\neq\ln x+C$$$$\int \frac{dx}{x}=\ln |x|+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dQ}{dt}=Q \rightarrow \frac{dt}{dQ}=\frac{1}{Q} \rightarrow t=\ln (Q)+c$. Then simply substitute in your initial conditions and you can find Q in terms of t after rearranging.